# How many organizations use CiviCRM?

Tags: core

This is a minor issue, but the count of organizations using CivCRM that is displayed on my civi home page seems to bounce around quite a bit.  For a time it showed numbers over 10,000.  Just now it says, "Used by over 6,273 organizations ..."  Last week I am pretty sure it was even lower but I did not record the number.
The 2015 [blog post](https://civicrm.org/blog/cividesk/how-many-organizations-use-civicrm-where-how) on this topic said, "There are close to 9,000 nonprofit or governmental organizations worldwide relying on CiviCRM ..." 
The updated widget on the same page reports 11,061 organizations as of June 5, 2017.
Just wondering if actual usage varies that much or if the measurement technique needs work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am the maintainer of the statistics for CiviCRM. There are between 10,000 and 11,000 organizations actively using CiviCRM at the moment. We suffered a hardware failure on the stats server hence the little fluctuation. The statistics will soon be back to normal. More information at https://stats.civicrm.org. Thanks.